# AngularStrap tabs load html fragment

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I am currently working on an AngularJS project with Twitter Bootstrap, and am trying to shift my Bootstrap directives into Angular. I decided on AngularStrap as it provided support for Bootstrap-Select (which I wasn't sure was the same for AngularUI). The [tabs example](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/tab) only covered static html though. Is there any way via AngularStrap or AngularJS to load html fragments dynamically, so that it is only called when the tab is clicked? My html fragments need to execute javascript as well.

My reason for doing so is two-fold. First is that each tab contains quite a lot of content, and I do not wish to load all the tabs at once, which will slow down the loading. The second reason is that I prefer a more modular approach to my source code and not put everything on the same html file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude) directive to load html fragments.

Using the AngularStrap Tab's example you can switch out the static content with the url to retrieve the html fragment. [Here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpEJky6AyBGzbJz5QkmV?p=preview) based on the AngularStrap Tab example with these key changes:

1) `$scope.tabs` now has a `page` property instead of content pointing to either template1.html, template2.html, or template3.html.

```
    $scope.tabs = [
    {title:'Home', page: 'template1.html'},
    {title:'Profile', page: 'template2.html'},
    {title:'About', page: 'template3.html'}
  ];
```

2) An `ng-include` is added to display the currently selected tab's page.

```
  <div ng-include src="tabs[tabs.activeTab].page"></div>
```

Note: I have the `ng-include` outside of the `ng-repeat` so each tab's page contents won't be loaded (even if not displayed).

Comment: This answer gave me what I needed to make an example using inline tab content. http://plnkr.co/edit/gS0i0V?p=preview

Comment: @Gloopy - the example does not seem to work now: then page content does not change the you hit a tab button. Do you know if this technique still works?

Comment: The following seems to work now: <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" title="{{ tab.title }}" name="{{ tab.title }}" ng-include src="tab.page" bs-pane>

Comment: @Gloopy, can u help me to have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203064/not-show-active-tab-title-correctly-in-angularstrap-tab