# ui-grid error: not added the 'ui-grid-resize-columns' directive to your grid definition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

ui-grid, I want to freeze the first column and the last column, then i use ui-grid-pinning, but when i resize the column, the console prints errors:

**The resizeable api is not registered, this may indicate that you've included the module but not added the 'ui-grid-resize-columns' directive to your grid definition.  Cannot raise any events.**

[image]

anyone can solve this problem? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably forgot to add `ui-grid-resize-columns` in your HTML, but I can't tell for sure without some code.

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-resize-columns></div>
```

Comment: my html: '<div class="grid" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection
   ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-pinning ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>'

Comment: @VinoDang Add ui-grid-resize-columns to it

Comment: i add ui-grid-resize-columns, it works for me! thank u

Comment: i also find a solution, add ui-grid-resize-columns="true" to the html like this: '<div class="grid" ui-grid-resize-columns="true" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-pinning ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>'

Comment: can u help me to have a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34203064/not-show-active-tab-title-correctly-in-angularstrap-tab

Answer (score 0):

if you add the attribute directive `ui-grid-resize-columns="true"` to your html like this:

```
<div class="grid" ui-grid-resize-columns="true" ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-selection
            ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-pinning ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

it also works for me!